# Random category URLs not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have been having problems with a custom taxonomy not working with a url. For example mysite.com/testcat/test1  will 404 but mysite.com/make/ford will work.

More troubling is that mysite.com/?make=ford&testcat=test1 will bring up my test page (both taxonomies where included).

Here is a clipping of the functions.php

```
register_taxonomy( 'testcat', 'videos', array( 'hierarchical' => True, 'label' => 'testcat', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you flush your rewrite rules after you created the taxonomy?

I tested your code (only changing `'videos'` to `'post'`) by adding to my functions PHP (TwentyEleven Theme WordPress 3.2 Trunk) then flushed my rewrite rules and created a post and gave it the testcat of test1 and the URL worked.

```
add_action( 'init', 'c3m_wp_stackx');
function c3m_wp_stackx() {
register_taxonomy( 'testcat', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => True, 'label' => 'testcat', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think I flushed my rewrite rules.... I originally went from the custom permalinks to standard then back to custom, but it was still broke. I then added a / to the end of the permalink, then removed it again and all is well. Was that flushing it? I couldn't find an easy way on google. Anyhow it seems to work now, Thanks!!

Comment: When you visit the permalink settings page your rewrite rules get flushed.  They also get flushed when you make a change to your permalink settings and click update.